# SQL - Find date closest to current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some trouble with my SQL query.
I got this table:

```
insert into Table1 (date, personssn)
insert ('2012-01-21 12:01:33', '123456789');
insert into Table1 (date, personssn)
insert ('2012-02-22 12:01:33', '123456789');
```

The problem is that I want to select the personssn who have a date CLOSEST to the current date. I've been working with "CURDATE()" but can't seem to get it to work. Anyone that can help me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Limit 1, absolute value (ABS) and date difference from sysdate/curdate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select  *
from    Table1
order by
        abs(now() - date) desc
limit   1
```

Comment: should be ordered Ascending (smallest date difference from now).If you want closest upcoming date I suggest adding a where clause to eliminate past dates (using abs would make a date 1 day ago ordered higher than a date in 2 days for example).

Answer (score 6):

Use datediff. It returns the Difference between two dates.
However, you can have dates before and after today in your database. That's why you need ABS() without it the smallest value would be selected first, but we want the value closest to 0.
IE a Date-Difference of 3 is “bigger” than -250, but 3 days off is closer. That is why you use the absolute value.

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.personssn 
  FROM Table1 AS t1
 ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(t1.date, NOW())) ASC
 LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with simple order by :

```
SELECT date,personssn FROM Table1 ORDER BY date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
with myCTE as (
SELECT to_date('21-Jan-2012 12:00') as mydate, '123456789' as myId FROM DUAL UNION
Select to_date('22-Feb-2012 12:00') as mydate, '123456789' FROM DUAL )
Select abs(sysdate-mydate) as diff, mydate, myID from myCTE order by diff
```

but this is oracle.. I'm not sure of the mysql text.

Answer (score 0):

Use MAX(date),If u want only one row as output else use date <= sysdate
otherwise how will u define closet to sysdate..

Comment: Probably because you can't use `max` to find the closest record, and even if you could, how would you display the corresponding SSN?

Comment: I didn't give the vote but I am assuming that it was because your method is making an assumption that the date in the table will never be past the current date and that selecting with max will just return the latest date in the system without regard to how close it is to the current date.