# Get closest date to current date sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

i know that may question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398661/sql-find-date-closest-to-current-date) but when i tried the answers they provide i got a different answer...

so i have a table and today is `06/02/2017`
**tblpres**

```
patID     pres       presDate
  1     |    asd     |    05/29/2017
  2     |    qwe     |    05/20/2017
  3     |    zxc     |    06/01/2017
  4     |    ety     |    05/27/2017
  5     |    ttt     |    05/18/2017
```

so i made a query to get the closest date to the current date but instead i get id 3 whch is the closest date to the current date i get a diff answer..

```
SELECT pres,presDate
FROM tblpres
WHERE patID = '20150518384'
ORDER BY presDate DESC
LIMIT 1

SELECT pres, presDate
FROM tblpres
WHERE patID = '20150518384'
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF(presDate, `06/02/2017` ) )
LIMIT 1

SELECT pres, presDate
from tblpres
WHERE patID = '20150518384'
order by abs('06/02/2017' - presDate) desc
limit 1

SELECT pres,presDate
FROM tblpres
WHERE `patID` = '20150518384' AND presDate < '06/02/2017'
ORDER BY presDate
LIMIT 1
```

this is the query i tried but nothing seems to work... i do get an answer for this query but the result is not what i expected..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ISO/ANSI standard date formats:

```
SELECT pres, presDate
FROM tblpres
WHERE patID = '20150518384'
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF(presDate, '2017-06-02') )
LIMIT 1;
```

Or, better yet, use `CURDATE()`:

```
SELECT pres, presDate
FROM tblpres
WHERE patID = '20150518384'
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF(presDate, CURDATE()) )
LIMIT 1;
```

If `presdate` is not actually a date, you might need to convert it to one:

```
SELECT pres, presDate
FROM tblpres
WHERE patID = '20150518384'
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF(str_to_date(presDate, '%m/%d/%Y'), CURDATE()) )
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: it works.. thankss.... but question is this the right approach when converting the date format? cause what i did was i use `$today = date('Y-m-d');$timestamp = strtotime($today);`
`$dmy = date("m/d/Y", $timestamp);` to convert the date format then use the query above although i get the date format to `06/02/2017` when i tried using the query above i get diff result...