# Date closest to current date in SQL (prior dates or future dates)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am running into a bit of an issue with finding out how to look for dates closest to the current date.  I looked at this among others:
[Get closest date to current date sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320092/get-closest-date-to-current-date-sql)

I also looked here: https://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/79502-get-closest-date

I am using MS SQL 2012 and there have been many questions asked about this, so I apologize for bringing it back up.  I can't seem to get my query to work.

Basically I have a table as follows:

```
ITEMNMBR | MINDATE    | MAXDATE    | CLOSESTDATE
------------------------------------------------
123456   | 2017-10-15 | 2017-11-04 | NULL
654321   | 2017-09-29 | 2017-12-08 | NULL
```

The current date would be today, '2017-10-03'.  We would find for item number '123456' the closest date of purchase is 2017-10-15.  For item number '654321' the closest date of purchase is 2017-09-29 as that happened much more recently than how long it will take for the next purchase to take effect (hence I am looking at an absolute value of the difference between the dates).  You'll have to forgive me, but the query I am including doesn't include the "CLOSESTDATE" column.  I've included it there to let you know that any of my calculations have rendered that column NULL.  So here's what I have:

```
--Lines commented below are not used in the current iteration of the query
--DECLARE @dt DATETIME
--SET @dt = GETDATE()

SELECT
    I.ITEMNMBR,
    MIN(PDATE1) AS MINDATE,
    MAX(PDATE1) AS MAXDATE
FROM dbo.IV00101 I 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT P.[Item Number], 
    P.[Req Date] AS PDATE1 
    FROM dbo.Purchases P
    WHERE ((P.[Document Status] = 'Open') AND 
    (P.[POStat] <> 'Closed') AND 
    (P.[POStat] <> 'Received')) AND P.[Req Date] >= DATEADD(d, -15, 
    DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()))
    ) AS P ON P.[Item Number]= I.ITEMNMBR
WHERE P.[Item Number] = '123456'
GROUP BY 
    I.ITEMNMBR
ORDER BY MINDATE DESC
```

When I run this query, I get the table I outlined previously, minus the "CLOSESTDATE" column.  The "CLOSESTDATE" column is what I want to use to display what date of purchase is closest to TODAY.  Basically, if a date of purchase happened three days ago and the next date of purchase is a month out, then I want to show the date of purchase from three days ago.  Also, the query can be written without using a subquery, but I was using other calculations within the subquery prior to reverting back to the rather simplistic original query.  Thus, the query can be written like this:

```
SELECT
    I.ITEMNMBR,
    MIN(P.[Req Date]) AS MINDATE,
    MAX(P.[Req Date]) AS MAXDATE
FROM dbo.IV00101 I 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Purchases P ON P.[Item Number] = I.ITEMNMBR
WHERE P.[Item Number] = '123456' ((P.[Document Status] = 'Open') AND 
    (P.[POStat] <> 'Closed') AND 
    (P.[POStat] <> 'Received')) AND P.[Req Date] >= DATEADD(d, -15, 
    DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY 
    I.ITEMNMBR
ORDER BY MINDATE DESC
```

Lastly, as you can see, I have a date constraint for the past 15 days so that anything older than that won't show up at all.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your query is way more complicated than your sample data -- making it hard to figure out the question that you are really asking.  You might start by providing accurate sample data, representative of the situations that might arise.

Comment: Do you just need to know this across the two dates in each row?

Comment: closest date to what ? which column?

Comment: I am confused by your complicated query by what seems to be a relative simple question. Are you just trying to find whether the `MINDATE` or `MAXDATE` is closest to today given a `ITEMNMBR`? And if the closest day is greater than 15, then `NULL` them? Or is the 15 days something you're just telling us that is part of your original query?

Comment: Not to mention just how much of that query is redundant...

Comment: I am simply trying to find the closest date to the current date for any item.  So whatever today's date is, I want to find the date of purchase closest to today's date.  The item number is there to show the item purchased.  The min date is the previous or next closest date for a purchase and the max is the farthest date from purchase.  So if we purchased an item two days ago and the next purchase is not until a week later, I need to show the date of two days ago.

Comment: @iamdave:  I rewrote the query below.  Did you not see that?

Comment: Yes.  My statement still stands.  For example,  you are using a `distinct` in a query that has a `group by` and using a `left join` then filtering the query in your `where` for only results that have a specific value in your right table...

Comment: Yes, that is leftover from a previous iteration of the query.  My apologies.  I will remove that.

Comment: Note the addition in my edited comment.  Also, what is that `dateadd` function doing with the `datediff` inside?

Comment: @iamdave:  at the moment, it was the best way I determined to get the date without the time for a GETDATE() function.  I only wanted '2017-10-03 00:00:00.000' for instance.  I suppose I could have used something else, though.  I'm not extremely skilled with date functions, hence my asking these questions.

Comment: @jderekc  You can do `cast(getdate() as date)` to remove the `time` element.  Also, be wary of future dates if you are using Simon's answer as is.

Comment: Thanks, @iamdave!  Learned something new that will surely help me going forward.  I appreciate your help and patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still not quite understanding your question, but I hope this gives you a start, you can try the rextester sample [here](http://rextester.com/CTXG85007)

But what it looks like to me is you need a simple case statement:

```
select ITEMNMBR
       ,case when abs(datediff(day, MINDATE, convert(date,getdate()))) > abs(datediff(day, MAXDATE, convert(date,getdate()))) then 'MINDATE is greater' else 'MAXDATE is greater' end as ClosestDate
from myTable
```

Kindly let me know if you have any questions. I'd be happy to help.

Comment: That's the solution.  Thanks!  I simply needed to know whatever date was closer.

Comment: You need to wrap the `datediff` functions in an `abs()` to avoid negative differences if any dates returned are in the future.

Comment: Yep.  @iamdave appears to be correct; still, this got me on the right path.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @iamdave Thanks, I have updated my query. And jderekc, I meant to put '...is closer' not greater. But I'm sure you figured that out. Cheers friend.

Answer (score 3):

I have taken your data and schema and made an approximation of what I believe your underlying data actually looks like.  From that, your problem is actually very simple:

```
declare @t table(ItemNumber int, ReqDate datetime, DocumentStatus nvarchar(100), POStat nvarchar(100))
insert into @t values
 (123456,'2017-10-15','Open','Not Closed')
,(123456,'2017-11-04','Open','Not Closed')
,(654321,'2017-09-29','Open','Not Closed')
,(654321,'2017-12-08','Open','Not Closed')

,(123456,'2017-10-11','Open','Closed')
,(123456,'2017-11-01','Closed','Not Closed')
,(654321,'2017-09-21','Closed','Not Closed')
,(654321,'2017-12-01','Open','Received');

select t.ItemNumber
      ,min(t.ReqDate) as MinDate
      ,max(t.ReqDate) as MaxDate

            -- Find the difference in days for both Min and Max dates, converting to positive numbers where negative,
      ,case when abs(datediff(d,min(t.ReqDate),getdate())) < abs(datediff(d,max(t.ReqDate),getdate()))
            then min(t.ReqDate)         -- And then return the appropriate one.
            else max(t.ReqDate)
            end as ClosestDate
from @t t
where t.DocumentStatus = 'Open'
    and t.POStat not in('Closed','Received')
    and t.ReqDate >= dateadd(d,-15,cast(getdate() as date))
group by t.ItemNumber
order by MinDate desc;
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| ItemNumber |         MinDate         |         MaxDate         |       ClosestDate       |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|     123456 | 2017-10-15 00:00:00.000 | 2017-11-04 00:00:00.000 | 2017-10-15 00:00:00.000 |
|     654321 | 2017-09-29 00:00:00.000 | 2017-12-08 00:00:00.000 | 2017-09-29 00:00:00.000 |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: You and Simon both posted a similar solution.  I don't think I can accept both as solutions, but your inclusion of absolute value was correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the initial part of the query with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
I.ITEMNMBR,
MIN(PDATE1) AS MINDATE,
MAX(PDATE1) AS MAXDATE
IF(ABS(DATEDIFF(MIN(PDATE1)-SYSDATETIME())) > 
ABS(DATEDIFF(MAX(PDATE1)-SYSDATETIME())),
MAX(PDATE1),MIN(PDATE1)) as CLOSESTDATE
```

Comment: Thanks!  This gave me ideas that were helped by Simon and iamdave.